# Quickest way to create a 'stepped' or zig-zagged path in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Is there a really simple way to create a stepped or zig-zagged path like this in Illustrator?

[image]

I created this by showing the grid, 'snapping' to it and drawing each step.

Ideally I'd like to find a way to draw a stepped or zig-zagged line by simply holding down a button, clicking and dragging. However I'm kind of expecting that creating a brush is the only way to do it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Effect > Distort & Transform > Zig Zag…

This will bring up a window to set the parameters of the line you draw (at 45° for the example you show).
[image]

Drag the line with the number of steps you wish to show. The steps can be rounded or angled.
[image]

Comment: You can get exact balues by using alt click when crateing the line with line tool as you can specify length